# something wrong with my php session in firefox

Tags: php, firefox

I have a php session problem in Firefox

After updating Firefox to Firefox 15 I got a problem in captcha, I test it on all browsers and it works perfectly!

At the top of the php file, I put this line:

```
$_SESSION['captcha']=rand(1000,9999);
```

Within the document, I use it to show the random captcha, but it always shows the previous random value not the new one!

**-** `captcha.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('content-type:image/jpeg');
    $text=$_SESSION['captcha'];

    $font=34;
    $height=40;
    $width=100;
    $rand=rand(-7,7);
    $image=imagecreate($width,$height);
    imagecolorallocate($image,255,255,255);
    $text_color=imagecolorallocate($image,0,50,80);

    for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++){
        $x1=rand(1,100);
        $y1=rand(1,100);
        $x2=rand(2,100);
        $y2=rand(1,100);

        imageline($image,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$text_color);
    }

    $fontfile='./angelicwar.ttf';
    imagettftext($image,$font,$rand,10,35,$text_color,$fontfile,$text);
    imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

---

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['captcha']=rand(1000,9999);
    echo "<img src='captcha.php'/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating the random value from your script, storing it in the session and then serving captcha.php, just have captcha.php generate the random value, draw it on the image, and save it in the session.

This way, your captcha value always matches what is shown on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['captcha'])) {
       $_SESSION['captcha']=rand(1000,9999); 
    }
```